# I have an employee file and an address file (that goes by a seq #) and I am trying to get the employees' current address

Tags: sql, join, max, ibm-midrange, db2-400

The employee file would have Clock#, Name etc
The address file has CLock#, seq, add1, add2, etc

I need to get the current (highest seq#) address for all active employees

I tried below but just got 1 line that had the highest sequence

```sql
SELECT HRPEMPM.EMEMPN, HRPEMPM.EMALPH, HRPE_ADD.EAADD1,         
       HRPE_ADD.EACITY, HRPE_ADD.EAPOST, HRPE_ADD.EASEQ 
FROM hrpempm, hrpe_add 
WHERE easeq = (select max(easeq) from hrpe_add ) and   
      HRPE_ADD.EAEMPN = emempn; 

Example 
Clock   Name           Status     Seniority 
1234    Mickey Mouse      A         2012/01/01
4567    Minnie Mouse      A         2015/06/01

Address file
Clock   Seq  Address 1            City        Prov
1234      1  124 King st.        Hamilton     Ont.
1234      2  525 Corman Ave.     Burlington   Ont.
1234      3  878 West 5th        Dundas       Ont.
4567      1  10 Mountain Ave.    Hamilton     Ont.
4567      2  777 Airport Rd      Mount Hope   Ont.  

Result expected
1234   Mickey Mouse    878 West 5th       Dundas       Ont.
4567   Minnie Mouse    777 Airport Rd     Mount Hope   Ont.
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Why are you choosing not to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help. How we find the address of an employee?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this approach:
Select the latest records first and then join on them:

```
;with a as(
  select *
         , rnk = row_number() over (partition by EAEMPN order by easeq desc)
  from hrpe_add
)
SELECT HRPEMPM.EMEMPN, HRPEMPM.EMALPH, HRPE_ADD.EAADD1,         
       HRPE_ADD.EACITY, HRPE_ADD.EAPOST, HRPE_ADD.EASEQ 
FROM hrpempm
join a on a.rnk = 1 and
      a.EAEMPN = hrpempm.emempn;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are close. I would try the following:

```
SELECT a.EMEMPN, a.EMALPH, b.EAADD1,         
       b.EACITY, b.EAPOST, b.EASEQ 
FROM hrpempm a
join hrpe_add b on a.EMEMPN = a.EAEMPN
WHERE b.easeq = (select max(easeq) from hrpe_add
                 where eaempm = a.emempn)
```

Instead of getting the max sequence number in the table, you need the max sequence number for the employee.